# Spring boot + Camel + CXF on Weblogic 12c: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/configuration/Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, weblogic, cxf

I'm trying to deploy Spring boot web application (WAR) on Weblogic 12c. The application uses Apache CXF and Camel to publish SOAP web services.

However, when I try to deploy the WAR, I get the following exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/cache/configuration/Configuration
```

I tried to to add following to `weblogic.xml` with no effect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation=http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

After adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get another error

```
javax.cache.CacheException: No CachingProviders have been configured
```

I think this dependency wouldn't be needed at all, but somehow Weblogic tries to take over application libraries (but if this is the case, I still wonder why Weblogic doesn't provide this dependency). At least I couldn't find any reference to this particular dependency, when inspecting POM dependency hierarchy.

Here are other dependencies of the project. It is using Spring boot starter parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tutoivon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Messaging</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Messaging Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <modules>
        <module>ApiComponent</module>
        <module>ServiceAComponent</module>
        <module>ServiceBComponent</module>
        <module>Broker</module>
        <module>BrokerB</module>
  </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>Messaging-parent</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf-transport</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And finally, here is the dependency tree of the specific WAR (note the Cache API is there only because I added it as explained earlier)

```
[INFO] tutoivon:ApiComponent:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:provided
[INFO] +- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.6.v20170531:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.6.v20170531:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.6.v20170531:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.6.v20170531:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.6.v20170531:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.6.v20170531:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-http-common:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf-transport:jar:2.20.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.16.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-kahadb-store:jar:5.14.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.5:compile
```

Questions:

- What is causing the problem?
- How does one actually troubleshoot this particular example to find the solution systemically?
- Is the only solution to debug Weblogic process to understand what is happening, or is there some patterns for solving these?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue after upgrading to camel 2.20.2 and cxf 3.2.1. With cxf 3.1.9 it looks fine again, maybe i find out more.

Comment: did you managed to solve this problem

Comment: @dursun Ultimately it was solved by removeing `jaxrs-api` dependency, which conflicted with WebLogic implementation and caused these cryptic exceptions. Unfortunately I can't recall further details.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.cache` is only a reference implementation.

You actually need to import a jcache library like `hazelcast`, and also provide for a caching provider configuration.

Answer (score 0):

set streamCache to false in camelContext xml.

`<!-- Camel Context Router Definitions  -->
    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="false">`